# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: indexCreatedVersionMajor is in the future: 8

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene, jena

I get an error in my text search with Jena and Lucene in runtime session. It said `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: indexCreatedVersionMajor is in the future: 8` The description error in below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: indexCreatedVersionMajor is in the future: 8
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.<init>(SegmentInfos.java:169)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:323)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:291)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:845)
at org.apache.jena.query.text.TextIndexLucene.openIndexWriter(TextIndexLucene.java:188)
at org.apache.jena.query.text.TextIndexLucene.<init>(TextIndexLucene.java:181)
at org.apache.jena.query.text.TextDatasetFactory.createLuceneIndex(TextDatasetFactory.java:109)
at org.apache.jena.query.text.TextDatasetFactory.createLucene(TextDatasetFactory.java:136)
at main.Search.createIndexedDataset(Search.java:92)
at main.Search.main(Search.java:50)
```

I think the version of Java i use may be the problem but i am not sure. I have searched for the error and i got [this](https://github.com/xiangp126/Latch/issues/6) but i don't understand. The full codes in below:

```
public class Search {
static String URI = "http://www.tutorialacademy.com/jenatext#";

static {LogCtl.setLog4j();
BasicConfigurator.configure();}
static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Search");

public static void main(String ... argv)
{
    TextQuery.init();
    Dataset ds = createIndexedDataset("tdb", "luceneindex", "hasLongText");
    loadData(ds, "res/data2.ttl");
    queryData(ds);

}

public static Dataset createIndexedDataset(String tdbPath, String lucenePath, String indexedProperty)
{
    Dataset graphDS = null;

    if(tdbPath == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Construct an in-memory dataset");
        graphDS = DatasetFactory.createMem();
    }else
    {
        System.out.println("Construct a persistant TDB based dataset to: " + tdbPath);
        graphDS = DatasetFactory.create();
    }
    //define the index mapping
    EntityDefinition entDef = new EntityDefinition ("uri", "text", ResourceFactory.createProperty(URI, indexedProperty));
    Directory luceneDir = null;

    // check for in memory or file based (persistant) index
    if (lucenePath == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Construct an in-memory lucene index");
        luceneDir = new RAMDirectory();
    }else
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Construct a persistant lucene index to: " + lucenePath);
            luceneDir = new SimpleFSDirectory(Paths.get(lucenePath));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //create new indexed dataset: insert operations are automatically indexed with lucene
    Dataset ds = TextDatasetFactory.createLucene(graphDS, luceneDir,  new TextIndexConfig(entDef));
    return ds;
}

public static void loadData(Dataset dataset, String file)
{
    System.out.println("Load data...");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
    try
    {
        Model m = dataset.getDefaultModel();
        RDFDataMgr.read(m, file);
        dataset.commit();
    }
    finally
    {
        dataset.end();
    }

    long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time = finishTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Loading finished after "+ time+ " ms");
}

public static void queryData(Dataset dataset)
{
    System.out.println("Query data...");
    String prefix = "PREFIX ta: <" + URI + ">"+
                                    "PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>";
    String query = "SELECT * WHERE" +
                                    "{ ?s text:query (ta:hasLongText 'g?eat')."+
                                    " ?s ta.hasLongText ?text . "+
                                    "}";

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);
    try
    {
        Query q = QueryFactory.create(prefix + query);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q,dataset);
        QueryExecUtils.executeQuery(q, qexec);
    }
    finally
    {
        dataset.end();
    }

    long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long time = finishTime- startTime;
    System.out.println("Query finished after " + time +" ms.");
}}
```

May i get some advises or help me or explain me the link i included above? Thank you.

Comment: *"I think the version of Java i use may be the problem but i am not sure."* it may be helpful to know what version that is, and what version your code has been compiled with.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca what about the link that I included? is that related?

Comment: Yes, I think it has more bearing than the java version you're using. It seems this is more about the different versions used to create the dataset you're loading.

Comment: It is Lucene saying that the file you are trying to read was created with a newer version that the one you are using.

Comment: +1 to @Thilo's comment, you've created the Lucene index with a newer version of Lucene than Jena is using.  You need to make sure that the versions of Jena (and Lucene) you are using are the same across your project or you will run into issues like this.